# Как получить доступ к полям объекта geoip2 в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geoip

Пытаюсь работать с локальной базой geoip2 GeoLite2-Country.mmdb. Но в оф. доках нет примера по работе конкретно с базой стран.

Модуль отдает объект, не могу извлечь из него данные словаря.

```
import geoip2.database
reader_country = geoip2.database.Reader('GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
response = reader_country.country('212.111.209.8')
print(response)
```

Вывод объекта `response>>>`

```
geoip2.models.Country({'continent': {'code': 'EU', 'geoname_id': 6255148, 'names': {'de': 'Europa', 'en': 'Europe', 'es': 'Europa', 'fr': 'Europe', 'ja': 'ヨーロッパ', 'pt-BR': 'Europa', 'ru': 'Европа', 'zh-CN': '欧洲'}}, 'country': {'geoname_id': 690791, 'iso_code': 'UA', 'names': {'de': 'Ukraine', 'en': 'Ukraine', 'es': 'Ucrania', 'fr': 'Ukraine', 'ja': 'ウクライナ共和国', 'pt-BR': 'Ucrânia', 'ru': 'Украина', 'zh-CN': '乌克兰'}}, 'registered_country': {'geoname_id': 690791, 'iso_code': 'UA', 'names': {'de': 'Ukraine', 'en': 'Ukraine', 'es': 'Ucrania', 'fr': 'Ukraine', 'ja': 'ウクライナ共和国', 'pt-BR': 'Ucrânia', 'ru': 'Украина', 'zh-CN': '乌克兰'}}, 'traits': {'ip_address': '212.111.209.8'}}, ['en'])
```

Напрямую обратится к полям `response.название_поля` не получается.

Обратится к словарю `response['continent']` тоже не получается:

> TypeError: 'Country' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

Согласно, документации https://geoip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geoip2.models.Country обращайтесь к полям как к атрибутам:

```
print(response)
print(response.continent)
print(response.continent.code)
print(response.continent.names)
print(response.continent.names['ru'])
```